# Server environment variables for apache

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables, plesk

I'm having trouble using Server environment variables with Apache.

Here is some info about the environment :

- OS : Debian 8.10 Jessie
- Web hosting plateform : Plesk
- PHP : 7.1.8

Executing scripts that use the environments variables work fine if I execute with PHP-CGI, but if I execute the script though the web page, I can't recuperate the environment variables.

The user is different when accessing the script through a web page but i can't load the environment variables for the page.

So far, i've tried setting the environment variables in :

- /etc/environment
- .bashrc of the user
- .htaccess
- apache2ctl
- PHP commande "putenv"
- ld.so.conf.d

So far, nothing works.

My question : how can i recuperate environment variables though a web page and not with php-cgi?

Thanks

Comment: it's the user difference that's the issue - needs to be the same user as the php-cgi I believe (if wrong someone comment and I'll remove)

Comment: Apache runs on another user (www-data by default). You should be able to see the environment settings if you add then to the file called `envvars`.

Comment: You should also make sure this is configured correctly: http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Comment: Thx, for the info, ill give a try later today and report back

Comment: Apparently envvars is not loaded when i start apache. I wonder is Plesk is interfering with the scripts Apaches loads when i restart apache

Answer (score 3):

If you use Plesk, you can add to "Additional directives" on PHP of your subscription:

```
[php-fpm-pool-settings] 
env[some_env_variable]="cool-value"
```

[image]

Then, when you check to phpinfo() you can see this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok after 3 weeks of trial and error i have found the solution for my case.

Here are the steps i had to take to make it work:

1. Change from PHP fastCGI to FPM served by apache
2. Add the following code to /opt/php7.1/etc/php-fpm.d/mydomaine.conf

> [php-fpm-pool-settings] env[LD_LIBRARY_PATH]="/var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/sqlanywhere16/lib64:/var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/sqlanywhere16/lib32"

3. Execute the commands :

> ldconfig -v
>
> ldconfig -p

4. Restart the server